# npm install fatal error with connection to github. webassembly and connection to github failed

Tags: laravel, npm, installation, webassembly

I had just started a Laravel project and went to go use npm install but it paused at webassembly dependancy and displayed Maximum call stack size exceeded. I tried to npm cache clean with and without --force. The node_modules directory isnt even there.

npm cache clean, npm cache clean --force and I cant delete a directory that does not exist [node_modules].

https://pastebin.com/Asrhnciu

```
3265 silly fetchPackageMetaData C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.EXE ls-remote -h -t git://github.com/dcodeIO/long.js.git
```

I'm not sure why npm install cant connect to github. I'm connected to the internet and everything looks to be normal until webassembly dep. I think the problem might be the command it is trying to run but im not sure if thats correct or how to fix it.

Comment: I had similar problem recently (on linux) it was caused by git not installed on the system - so check if git is installed and  on PATH

Comment: I actually later found that slow enterprise networks dont like github, so in conclusion dont npm install on school wifi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

School wifi was the solution, it couldnt make the connectionm fast enough for node to accept it...